# Read from a .ini in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

So I am using GetPrivateProfileInt, to read some variables off a .ini file in c++. I am using:

```
int I_Hate_This = GetPrivateProfileInt("test", "test", 30, "C:\\Users\\JarodAnly\\Documents\\work.ini");
```

The .ini file is:

```
[test]
test=60
```

I seem to be constantly getting the output of 30. So could someone let me know where I made my error. Cheers.

Comment: Try using `GetPrivateProfileIntA`. Otherwise, you probably need to use Unicode strings.

Comment: Try to remove the semicolon after test=60

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No luck, thanks for the advice tho. Unicode strings honestly sounds like such a pain in the ass, for a simple thing.

Comment: @SzőkeSzabolcs Thanks but it didnt fix it ;(

Comment: What is the return code of ``GetLastError()``?

Comment: @ub3rst4r There is no error, it just sets the value to 30.

Comment: You have the wrong file path, and most likely `GetLastError` returns "file not found error".

Comment: Did you read the Documentation? It tells you that these functions were deprecated 20 years ago and should not be used. Stop using them. Use a native c++ ini parser. Or perhaps use a more powerful format like JSON or yaml.

Comment: I agree with @BarmakShemirani, add the file presence/accessibility check before GetPrivateProfileInt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the number.

It should be:

> [test]
>   test=60

Comment: I tried that, nothing, I can't believe I was so stupid to do that :P